# Use string to set name of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to set one array equal to another via a string.
I have the following array:

```
var apartment234 = ["01.07.2017","02.07.2017","03.07.2017","04.07.2017","05.07.2017","06.07.2017","07.07.2017"];
```

And I have the following string which equals the array above (`apartment234`).

```
unavailable = "apartment" + ausgewzimmer;
```

If I now want a function to return something based on the array as shown below, it doesn't return anything.

```
return !!(unavailable.indexOf(date.format('DD.MM.YYYY')) > -1);
```

However, if I use the array directly, it does work.

```
return !!(apartment234.indexOf(date.format('DD.MM.YYYY')) > -1);
//returns desired values
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong... `unavailable` does equal `apartment234` as in `unavailable = "apartment234"`. Why doesn't it function? Could you please help me?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the best way to do it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: `apartment234` looks like something that should be indexed: `apartment[234] = [...]` so that its easy to look up by index ...

Comment: @Aron `ausgewzimmer` depends on a selection HTML element or rather it's value... consequently, I have numerous arrays named according to the value of `unavailable` and would like to use strings in the function or more precisely in the return...

Comment: @George sorry, I couldn't find it :/ thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a object with property "apartment234", then it can be accessed using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```js
var obejct = {
  "apartment234": ["01.07.2017", "02.07.2017", "03.07.2017", "04.07.2017", "05.07.2017", "06.07.2017", "07.07.2017"]
};

var unavailable = "apartment" + 234;
console.log(obejct[unavailable]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The string "apartment234" is not the same as the array instance apartment234.

When you do this:

```
unavailable.indexOf(....)
```

You are just calling the `indexOf()` method on the string.

You could use the eval() method to accomplish this:

```
unavailable = eval("apartment" + ausgewzimmer);
```

`eval()` evaluates, or executes the given string as JS code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach when it can be done without calling `eval()` via `window[unavailable]` and we don't know how `ausgewzimmer` is getting created.

Comment: Why not? It's created via `$("#element").val()` from an HTML... why wouldn't you use it? And is it ok to use it here? @George

Comment: @Moritz `eval()` [has problems](https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval) with performance and with people being able to inject code into your js. `eval()` isn't always evil but (to me) it should normally be a last resort.

Comment: eval() is usually the "easy" way to accomplish things like this, but like the others have pointed out, there are other ways which are better.  I usually don't use eval(), I try to do things differently.  I thought it was OK to mention here as an easy option.

Comment: @HaukurHaf eval is useful in this case if you don't know what scope the object is on :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to have string-representation of your array as return of function calls, can't you just do regular Array.toString() and String.split(",") methods to handle this?